# What day is it again?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> Post Office, Refugee, Post Office, Photography, Milk, Food, Nelson
>   Mandela, Post Office, Youth, Hiroshima, Army, Army, Youth, Photography

**What day is it?**

Comment: Sounds like the plot to a Nolan WWII film.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To explain

> where the mapping found in Bass's answer comes from

note that

> each of the things listed has an official Day named after it, and the alphabet positions are the day-of-month numbers. E.g., Hiroshima Day is the **6th** of August, Youth Day (according to the UN; some countries have their own) is the **12**th of August, and Nelson Mandela Day is the **18th** of July. Hence F, L, R respectively.

Comment: Nice, that's what I thought too. Did you manage to work back from the solution to figure out which country's army we were supposed to celebrate? (I gave up with the googling at that point, because the time zone of the question didn't line up with the solution in a very sensible manner for any of the possibilities.)

Comment: @Bass India­­­­

Comment: @noedne beat me to it — Army Day is Jan 15th in India.

Comment: I didn't try, I'm afraid, I just checked enough to be sure I was right :-). The correspondence described here is what I thought of instantly when I saw the puzzle several hours ago -- but I looked up one of them and it didn't seem to work out, so I didn't post anything. Then I came back here, saw @pirate's comment on your answer, and gave it another go. The thing that confused me wasn't the army one but the Post Office; it turns out that the first thing I found was nonsense.

Answer (score 12):

It is

> April Fools.

Because

> ```
>  Post Office    = I
>  Refugee        = T
>  Post Office    = I
>  Photography    = S
>  Milk           = A
>  Food           = P
>  Nelson Mandela = R 
>  Post Office    = I
>  Youth          = L
>  Hiroshima      = F
>  Army           = O
>  Army           = O
>  Youth          = L
>  Photography    = S
> ```
>
> (A simple substitution cipher)

Comment: Yeah that's right, but the words aren't random (hint in title)

Comment: @pirate, Given that they require detailed knowledge of miscellaneous days celebrated in more or less random countries around the world, they might as well be. :-)

Answer (score 11):

It's the 31st of March, 2019 AD. Judging by the display on PSE, April 1st has never been closer.

Comment: @pirate It is a joke answer, in the spirit of April 1st. If it is not welcome, I will delete it.